# I want to improve Salesforce1 Mobile performance

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, performance, chrome

I am having problems with the performance on Salesforce1 Mobile specifically the loading times of visualforce pages, I have tested those visualforce pages independently using the developer console and works well, I also tested those pages in Salesforce1 with compatible Android and Apple devices with Wi-Fi connections greater than 10 Mbps.

At this moment I have made some measurement using the Google Chrome DevTools Timeline using the SF1 browser access with one.app, and I found than the loading time of Salesforce1 Mobiles is affected for some JavaScript that are hosted in force.com but I doesn't found significantly high loading or execution time related with the content in my visualforce pages.

There are other specific tools to monitoring the performance in Salesforce1? I want to know if I can improve in some way the performance of SF1 and what other actions can I execute to get my goal.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mechanisms to improve perfomance

1)Use [visualforce remoting objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm) or [Javascript remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm)
    to build your page .Dont use getters and setters or action functions
    with apex:form as that will involve view state .(Avoid pageblocks
    ,apex:form and all tags that carry view state ).If you see getters
    and setters all read only properties can be made transients

2)As far as possible handle logic at client end itself with
    Javascript and use server to push or retrieve data .Handle all
    validations at client site itself .

3)Use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) process to concatenate and minify all
    your Javascript code to improve performance .Infact use
    [webpacks](https://webpack.github.io/docs/) if possible that will improve perfomance.

4)Use frameworks like [angular](https://angular.io/) or [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) to improve
    performance and handle logic at client end

[Lightning components](https://developer.salesforce.com/lightning/platform-features) are in GA and has excellent support for SF1 apps and hence its not a bad idea to build lightning components and apps rather than using visualforce .

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am currently using remote objects, I was expecting if there are a tool that can I use directly with the APK of Salesforce1. But I think that in this moment a improvement in performance depends mostly in the next updates of the Salesforce1 Mobile App or maybe work in a native app using the SDK.

My next step before create a Native App is try some javascript framework and learn about lightning components if that means a better time in loading times.

Thanks.